# External Javascript files extremely slow in IE 8,9,10,11

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer, cdn

My site calls some JS files from Google & Microsoft's libraries. Example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/4/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My site loads fine on Chrome & Firefox, but when I open it in IE (8,9,10,11), it takes ages to load. Looking at HTTP Watch, the waterfall shows every external JS file taking 20+ seconds to load. So the total site load time is upwards of 60 seconds.

If I open the JS files directly in IE, it loads instantaneously:

```
https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/4/MicrosoftAjax.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
```

It's only slow loading when called through my website. My website is on a CDN and loads correctly when spoofing directly to our origin server. The external JS files only slow down when the page is loaded through the CDN.

Additionally, on some companies/networks/VPNs, the CDN site loads fine on IE. On other companies/networks/VPNs, we see this slowness.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: have you tried using `http` instead of `https`

Comment: The issue is that if we have any http content on the website, the browser will show the page as having insecure content.

Comment: Right, that'd be expected behavior. Really the protocol shouldn't slow it down that much, and would be unnoticeable due to browser caching on the second attempt. I'm not there and couldn't even verify whatever you're seeing with such little information.

Comment: Just guessing but, is it a corporate environment? Could some policy is been applied (some heavy security check)?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I fail to see what the CDN of your website has to do with this. I would think the only CDN that matters is that of the resource file, unless your CDN serves the file through a proxy. You could tracert a few times to see if there's anything going on over the network. I'm not sure how browsers validate certificates, but could that also be at play?

Comment: @VitorCanova, it was a security policy with McAfee - thank you!! vol7ron, thank you also for your help in troubleshooting